# Trying to install Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 but it installs Ubuntu GNOME 16.04?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, system-installation, 15.10, 16.04

I'm Using Ubuntu GNOME right now.Everythings fine.I didn't look at the 16.04 update first and installed it.Then i looked up the updates and i saw that Ubuntu 16.04 does not support AMD RADEON graphics.So i tried to burn Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 on the installing medium but when I boot from the installing medium it opens Ubuntu GNOME 16.04!Please help and I can download Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 too.*I also tried with Ubuntu MATE 15.10 but it did it again it installed Ubuntu MATE 16.04*

Comment: My guess is the computer isn't booting whatever installation media you're using. It would be helpful to know how you created the media and whether you're using USB or DVD.

Comment: Im using usb and it boots actually.But its not 14.04 it opens 16.04.I guess the files are misplaced.

Comment: What did you use to create it?

Comment: Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator ( I was on Normal Unity and i changed it to Gnome.)

Comment: OK. Did you format the USB stick beforehand, are you sure you have the correct file, and are you _sure_ that it's booting from the USB?

Comment: It will boot to the files that are on the media.  If the media on the USB drive is Windows, it will boot to Windows.  If the the media on the card is Ubuntu 14.04 that is what it would boot to.  It can't boot to files that are not on the media that you are using.  It can only boot to the actually files that are on the media.  You'll have to be very careful to check what you have installed on the USB drive... you'll find that if you boot to that drive, it will boot to the files that are actually on that drive.

Comment: Yes i did.I don't know if it is the correct but i think they are misplaced.And yes I'm very sure its booting from the USB.

Comment: I guess they are misplaced im sure i downloaded 14.04! nvm im going to try 15.10 if its the same i'll write.But if it works i'll write again

Comment: That's the key... the problem.  Since you are not sure,  you have most likely booted to a drive that you didn't intend to boot to.  It booted to the actual files that were installed on that USB drive.

Comment: Ohhh.I guess they are misplaced.I clicked on Ubuntu 16.04 and it shows 14.04 thank you for your help.I found it.

Comment: no they don't my brother clicks 14.04 and it opens 14.04.But mine, don't.I guess thats from browser.I didn't used firefox or chrome.THX

Answer (score 0):

Ok.I solved it.If you guys have the same problem,do what i did.
-Go to Ubuntu GNOME download page
-Click on Ubuntu 16.04 and it will show you 14.04.
Also my brother clicked 14.04 it opened 14.04 but at my computer it didn't.I think its from the browser.